# What does "Kafka Enhanced Topic" mean?

Tags: apache-kafka

Sometimes I meet this collocation. E.g. "Kafka UDF Enhanced Topics" or "Kafka JSON-LD Enhanced Topics".

I looked at [Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/), but it has no information about Enhanced Topics.

Comment: Where do you find this "Enhanced Topic" reference?  There is no such thing in Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you misread it, even google doesn't know about kafka enchanced topics:

https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22Kafka+UDF+Enhanced+Topics
https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22kafka+enhanced+topic%22